# How to create a React Native login with PHP and consisting login session?

Tags: php, api, react-native, authentication, session

I'm about to start a new project with React Native to create an app. Coming from web development (mainly PHP, SQL), I'm wondering about how to create a login session in the app.

While, on the web, you've a session on the web server and a cookie stored locally - what do you use then for a React Native app, also providing security with that?

I think one may use an API for that to validate user data with a POST request, but then afterwards I'm asking myself how to create a persistent and secure session?

I hope you understand what I mean. Does somebody has an example for that or a type of simple "flow-chart" to help me understand and/or finding a way how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Don't be discouraged if your question gets closed.  Its not a bad question from a human standpoint, it's just too broad for stackoverflow.  If I were you I would look for an open source app that does what you're looking for and look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

React Native use something similar to session. It uses async storage to store something like a cookie when the user is log in and will check if the "cookie" is still valid while opening the app.

I let you have a look on [redux-react-native-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-react-native-session).
There is also all made API like [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) where you just have to make call to their API's functions to log in, disconnect, ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Isn't it necessary to send the session cookie with everything API request then, and is that safe? How would you encrypt it while using a JSON-based API for example? Is it necessary to have these things like secret key etc. here (read it on the internet yesterday)?

Comment: It would be a very bad idea to store any kind of secure information in AsyncStorage as it's not encrypted or secure in any way. Please opt instead for either `expo-secure-store` or `react-native-keychain`.